Salesforce api/interface to get limits on license
I have a use case where we send metering data to Salesforce against a license purchased from salesoforce in the CPQ flow. The license has some limits/quota on which bases salesforce will apply the metered data and do the billing.
Now I have couple of questions as below:-

I want to get the limits/quota of the license from Salesforce when the license is purchased, updated or deleted. Is there any webhook or notification sent by Salesforce for same. Please provide references.

More of architecture question:-
I have a separate limiting microservice and metering microservice. I want the limiting service to get the notification from Salesforce regarding the limits/quota update of license and metering service to send the metered data to Salesforce. Is there any standard architecture to achieve limiting and metering from the client side. Like have limiting and metering in same service or salesforce handle the limiting and raise notifications to interested clients etc.


